# Can I use Winston logger in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, winston

I setup a Winston logger in my development machine with a Node.js server. Based on the dbState I change the name of the log file:

```
const { createLogger, transports, format } = require('winston');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const dbState = keys.db.state;

const customFormat = format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.printf((info) => `${info.timestamp} [${info.level.padEnd()}]: ${info.message}`));

const logger = createLogger({
  format: customFormat,

  transports: [
    new transports.File({ filename: `${dbState}-error.log`, level: 'error' }),
    // After it reaches 10MB, it will create a new file and start writing to that
    new transports.File({ filename: `${dbState}-combined.log`, maxsize: 10000000 }),
  ],
});

logger.stream = {
  write(message, _encoding) {
    console.log(message.trim());
    logger.info(message.trim());
  },
};

module.exports = logger;
```

I have pushed this update to Heroku now, where the log file is probably increasing. Is there a way to access this log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Winston, but avoid its file transports. File-based logging is an antipattern on Heroku:

- Any changes to the filesystem (e.g. log files ) are lost whenever the dyno restarts due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)
- [Dynos restart frequently and unpredictably](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts):

  > Cycling happens for all dynos, including one-off dynos, so dynos will run for a maximum of 24 hours + 216 minutes.
- Logging to a local file breaks as soon as you want to scale horizontally by adding more dynos

Heroku [treats logs as event streams](https://12factor.net/logs), so consider using Winston's [Console transport](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/blob/master/docs/transports.md#console-transport). This should make logs from all of your dynos show up in the standard event stream.

If you wish, you can use [a logging addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#logging) like Logtail or Papertrail to query your logs downstream.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can access Heroku log files through the command line tools.

```
heroku login
heroku run bash -a APPNAME
```

Once you have a session running you should be able to run `ls` or `cat` as you wish to read the file names. Also, once you are done be sure to `exit`.